# Looking for free software to create a topological map of a network

Tags: linux, network-scanner

I'm already familiar with NMap and other such betwork scanners, but I'm looking for a tool that can create a visual map of my network.

Is there a free tool available for Linux that can accomplish this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does your router not support such a function?

Comment: Routers usually don't support that.

Answer (score 1):

Nmap's GUI (Zenmap) [can show a topological map of a network](https://nmap.org/book/zenmap-topology.html). It can be found under **Topology** tab.

It works on Linux and it's usually packaged with Nmap.

Answer (score 1):

[ntop/ntopng/nprobe](https://www.ntop.org/products/traffic-analysis/ntop/)  are also worth a closer look. Scroll down on linked page for sccreenshots.

There is an option to visualize "flows" between machines. Not sure if it cool visualizations are available in the free editions though.